# I have a discord bot, logged in and everything but it doesn't react to the message

Tags: discord.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [8] });

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log("Logged in as bot!");
  //client.user.setActivity(`Locating new targets for synthesis.`, { type: "WATCHING" });
})

client.on('messageCreate', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'ping') {
    msg.channel.send('pong')
  }
})

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

The bot is online, discord methods and stuff seems to be right, what am I doing wrong?(also didn't work with just msg.reply)

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with your intents. You have to specify what your bot may do and what information it may receive. This is done via intents.

[This website](https://discord-intents-calculator.vercel.app/) should help you out with defining your intents, and generating the integer you need for the necessary privileges.

For instance, intents `4608` should give you access to what you need.

I suggest reading the [gateway intents documentation](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents), to clear any uncertainty.

Comment: Hmm I thought "Bot Permissions" panel from discord that gives you codes like this is what I need, it gave me 8 for Administrator.
Thanks it finally works.

Comment: I added the gateway intents documentation for a more elaborate description of intents